# Calculate difference in minutes between created_at and current time in Laravel

Tags: laravel, timestamp, difference, subtraction

I want to show in a field the time someone is waiting, and I want to do that by subtracting created_at time by current time in minutes

this is my table

```
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Ordernummer</th>
                                    <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Kenteken</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Wachttijd</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach($orders as $order)
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">{{ $order->ordernumber }}</th>
                                        <td scope="row">{{ $order->email }}</td>
                                        <th scope="row">{{ $order->numberplate }}</th>
                                        <td scope="row">{{ $order->created_at }}</td>
                                        <td scope="row">
                                            @if( $order->status == 0)
                                                Open
                                            @else
                                                Afgehandeld
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

And where this is written  `<td scope="row">{{ $order->created_at }}</td>`
I want to show there the difference in minutes.

Thanks already

Answer (score 4):

I assume your `$order->created_at` is Carbon instance, so you can use:

```
<td scope="row">{{ $order->created_at->diffInMinutes(\Carbon\Carbon::now()) }} minutes ago</td>
```

if `$order->created_at` is pure mysql format not Carbon instance just convert/create it:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $order->created_at)->diffInMinutes(\Carbon\Carbon::now())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Carbon` to calculate difference in minutes like so

```
<td scope="row">{{ now()->diffInMinutes($order->created_at) }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Carbon::diffInMinutes` to get the minutes differnt,
or you can use `Carbon::diffForHumans` to get more readable statement

```
$order->created_at->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now());
```

// that would be:   **5**

```
$order->created_at->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now());
```

and this would be: **5 minuets ago**